# How to encode DateTime values in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following DataFrame in PySpark:

```
itemid  eventid    timestamp
134     30         2016-07-03 
134     32         2016-07-03 
125     32         2016-07-10
```

How can I encode `timestamp` as a random number or random string? For example:

```
itemid  eventid    timestamp   timestamp_enc
134     30         2016-07-03  1
134     32         2016-07-03  1
125     32         2016-07-10  2
```

DataFrame:

```
df = (
    sc.parallelize([
        (134, 30, "2016-07-02"), (134, 32, "2016-07-02"),
        (125, 32, "2016-07-10"),
    ]).toDF(["itemid", "eventid", "timestamp"])
    .withColumn("timestamp", col("timestamp").cast("timestamp"))
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function **unix_timestamp** to create the "random" number:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, unix_timestamp

df = (
    sc.parallelize([
        (134, 30, "2016-07-02"), (134, 32, "2016-07-02"),
        (125, 32, "2016-07-10"),
    ]).toDF(["itemid", "eventid", "timestamp"])
    .withColumn("timestamp", col("timestamp").cast("timestamp"))
)

df.withColumn("timestamp_enc", unix_timestamp(col("timestamp"), format='yyyy-MM-dd')).show()
```

creates:

```
+------+-------+-------------------+-------------+
|itemid|eventid|          timestamp|timestamp_enc|
+------+-------+-------------------+-------------+
|   134|     30|2016-07-02 00:00:00|   1467417600|
|   134|     32|2016-07-02 00:00:00|   1467417600|
|   125|     32|2016-07-10 00:00:00|   1468108800|
+------+-------+-------------------+-------------+
```